# Do not create directory when using wget with `--page-requisites` option

Tags: wget

I'm using `wget` with `--page-requisites` option. I'd like to combine this option with `--directory-prefix`. So for example when calling `wget --page-requisites --directory-prefix=/tmp/1 https://google.com` would download the google page to `/tmp/1/` directory without creating it's own folder (like `google.com`).

I'd expect the google homepage to end up at `/tmp/1/index.html`

Is there a way to do this without creating some kind of script that would move the files where I want them to be?

Answer (score 1):

Ok using option `--no-directories` seems to do the trick.